# Wordpress Custom Post Type Form Redirects to Page Not Found

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have been reading extensively about this and cannot seem to find a resolution. I have created a form in PHP which I want to submit to the same page I am on. I have read that there are some name's that wordpresses reserves such as "name" - which I am not using. Does anyone have any idea why this redirects to page not found upon submission?

http://hybridhosting.net/markeim/properties/52-coles-road/

```
<form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" id="my_favorite_nonce" name="my_favorite_nonce" value="a87e4a44aa"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/markeim/properties/52-coles-road/">        <input type="hidden" name="form_title" value="brokercontact">
        <input type="hidden" name="brokers" value="testemail@gmail.com">
      <p>
        Your Name 
        <span>
          *
        </span>

      <br>

    <input type="text" id="yourname" name="yourname" class="ink">
  </p>

  <p>
    Your E-mail 
    <span>
      *
    </span>

  <br>

<input type="text" id="youremail" name="youremail" class="ink">
</p>

<p>
  Your Message
  <span>
    *
  </span>

<br>

<textarea cols="" rows="" id="yourmessage" name="yourmessage" class="lab"></textarea>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="submit" class="sending" value="Contact Broker">
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Interesting problem. Perhaps posting to itself (something like /?page_id=500) instead of "".

Comment: @dotty This is actually a custom post, not a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something to do with your hidden input fields, not sure what. When I delete the nodes from dev tools and submit the form, it goes through fine!

Delete the hidden input field with name="brokers" and you'll see

I'm guessing WP uses the term "brokers" for something, please see here:
http://contactform7.com/faq/are-there-any-reserved-or-unavailable-words-for-the-name-of-an-input-field/

Comment: Oh wow... you're correct. I didnt even check for brokers I didnt think there was any chance that was the issue. THanks so much Rich!

Comment: Had the exact same problem last week with with an input name="name"! Drove me insane for a good couple of hours